# Get ALL the lines that contains EXACTLY all the patterns in a text file

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to filter all the lines that match exactly with ALL the patterns in the text file contain the next lines:

```
c1 and c2 and c15 => r1
c1 and c3 and c11 => r2
c1 and c2 => r3
c2 and c16 => r4
```

I have tried with `grep` using:

```
grep -w "c1" file | grep -w "c2"
```

It returns the correct answer:

```
c1 and c2 and c15 => r1
c1 and c2 => r3
```

But when I nested more than 6 `grep` commands, it returns an error:

```
Command ' grep' not found
```

but there are 18 similar ones

I understand that there exists a limit in the number of `grep` commands that I can nest. Does exist another way to do this operation?

Thank a lot.

Comment: `Command ' grep' not found` indicates an error in your command line, possibly related to some issue with quoting. Please show the exact command that generates this error.

Comment: Can you provide a sample "file"? And what is "r1" and so on?

Comment: This command works fine: grep -w "c1" 01_ini_state.find | grep -w "c2" | grep -w "c3" | grep -w "c4" | grep -w "c5" | grep -w "c7". But when I added one more pattern the error message appears. So, I understand that I can only nested 6 grep commands.

Comment: The error message is : "Command ' grep' not found, but there are 18 similar ones."

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the command line where you got this error message, along with the error message, into the question. Also, please provide an exact (possibly anonymized) example of the input file, along with desired output.

Comment: Pipelines can be arbitrarily long; there is no limitation. You likely have a typo, and this is why we are asking you to show the long pipeline that generates the error.

Comment: This is the completed command that generates the error: grep -w "c1" 01_ini_state.find | grep -w "c2" | grep -w "c3" | grep -w "c4" | grep -w "c5" | grep -w "c7"  | grep -w "c8"

Comment: Copying from the edit view, there's a non-breaking space character in that error message there, like I suspected. SE just keep stuff like those and tabs intact in the post view itself, which really doesn't help with issues like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` :

```
awk -v arrayvar="c1,c2" '
{
    split(arrayvar, a, ",")
    for(i in a){
        r="(^|" FS ")" a[i] "($|" FS ")"
        if($0 !~ r) next
    }
    print
}' input
```

We are using the [`split()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function.

> `split(s, a [, r [, seps] ])`
>
> Split the string s into the array a and the separators array seps on
> the regular expression r, and return the number of fields.

We then check that the line contains exactly all the patterns.

`r="(^|" FS ")" a[i] "($|" FS ")"` regex that start either by `^` or `FS` (Field separator), have your pattern `a[i]`, then ends by either `$` or `FS`

If the line does not contains the pattern we skip it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Command ' grep' not found
> ```

This sounds a lot like a typo where you have hit a non-breaking space after the pipe character, instead of a regular one. Note how the space is part of the command name, and for a regular space, that would require explicitly quoting or escaping the space, e.g. with

```
... | " grep"`
```

But with some keymaps (like mine), the pipe is AltGr-something, and the non-breaking space is AltGr-space, which makes the mistake happen if you're just a bit too slow to release the modifier key in between.
(Or with  Option instead of AltGr on Macs, same thing)

Try to retype the command line. A longer-term workaround might be to modify your keymap to remove that trap, or to start typing `... |grep` instead, at least that way you're more likely to get a more visible difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` has PCRE-support, try something like:

```
grep -P '(?=.*c1 )(?=.*c2)' file
```

Note the space after `c1`, so it won't match `c15`.